# Select statement using Chinese characters

Tags: sql

i have a table store chinese address and english address
i need to select address for compare which address do not same.

when i select english address can compare which one different but chinese address  cannot.

anybody advise? thanks

For Example:

```
output:
id  t1.address  t2.address
1   一三        一三
2   三三        三五
```

i want to output

```
id  t1.address  t2.address 
2   三三        三五
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, you can use left join like below sample

```
SELECT
    t1.id,
    t1.address AS t1address,
    t2.address AS t2address 
FROM
    t1
    LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id 
WHERE
    t1.address != t2.address
```

Comment: you can share the errors when excute.  check the tablename and field are right in sql

Answer (score 0):

do you mean compare the value of chinese address field and english address field?
If so, you can see below sample

```
SELECT CASE English
    WHEN Chinese THEN 'same'
    ELSE 'not same'
END as IsEqual
 FROM [dbo].[Sd_Biz_7T] WHERE English= '<The Select Value>';
```

Comment: sorry for my unclear expression, i want to compare chinese address field from two table but when i WHERE the chinese address field it output the same address / not same address. but i want output not same address by two table.thanks!

Comment: you can check my new post